# perl: grep and map in one operation

Tags: list, perl

Is there a way to perform a `grep` and a `map` in a single operation in perl?  Similar to the way that python can perform list comprehension:

```
files = [{ 'path':'/path/to/file1',
           'size':123},
         { 'path':'/path/to/file2',
           'size':987},
         { 'path':'/path/file3',
           'size':1234},
         { 'path':'/path/to/file4',
           'size':543},
         { 'path':'/path/to/my/file5',
           'size':1357}]
large_filepaths = [file['path'] for file in files if file['size'] > 1024]
```

In Perl, I need to do a `grep` to filter out the large files, then a `map` to get the specific values I want:

```
my $files = [ { path=>'/path/to/file1',
                size=>123},
              { path=>'/path/to/file2',
                size=>987},
              { path=>'/path/file3',
                size=>1234},
              { path=>'/path/to/file4',
                size=>543},
              { path=>'/path/to/my/file5',
                size=>1357} ];
my @large = grep { $_->{size} > 1024 } $files;
my @large_filepaths = map { $_->{path} } @large;
```

Is there a simple way to run this in a single operation, or do I have to use 2 statements (or one compound statement)?

Comment: `grep { $_->{size} > 1024 } $files;` ... That is likely to make you sad. You need to dereference `$files` as in `@$files` or using my favorite new syntax `$files->@*`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One statement with `map { ... } grep { ... } @$files` is the "standard" way to do it and the closest equivalent to what you're doing in Python.

Technically it's possible to do it in a single `map`, because `map` can return any number of values for each input value, including zero ­— so you can do something like
`map { $_->{size} > 1024 ? $_->{path} : () } @$files`, but that's substantially less clear and I wouldn't recommend it in general.

Answer (score 4):

1. `$files` is an array reference, therefore `values $files` does not make sense.
2. `map BLOCK` and `grep BLOCK` tend to be slower than `map EXPR` and `grep EXPR`, respectively. Prefer the latter if you can.

```perl
my @large_filepaths =
    map $_->{path},
    grep $_->{size} > 1024,
    @$files;
```

Comment: `values $files` works with the experimental (but now deprecated) feature that automatically dereferenced reference variables

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a simple way to run this in a single operation,

You can do it as one compound statement:

```
my @large_paths = map { $_->{path} } grep ...;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with just a call to `map` if you want

```
my @large_filepaths = map { $_->{size} > 1024 ? ( $_->{path} ) : ( ) } @$files;
```

but I think a combined `map`/`grep` is clearer.